# How do I send the change output from an input to fundchannel to a taproot address instead of to a SegWit v.0 address?

Tags: lightning-network, core-lightning, change, ln-opening-channels, utxo-management

Is there a way send the change output from an input to fundchannel to a taproot address instead of to a SegWit v.0 address?

I have only one large utxo in onchain funds of my Core Lightning node. Its address is a
SegWit v.0 address, that starts with `bc1q`. I want to open a channel with `lightning-cli fundchannel`. Is there a way to send the change from this input (not needed for the opening of the channel) to a taproot address (i.e. a SegWit v.1 address that starts with `bc1p`) instead of to a SegWit v.0 address? I am worried because my experience with [`lightning-cli newaddr`](https://docs.corelightning.org/reference/lightning-newaddr) is that  by default it generates a SegWit v.0 address.

Comment: So, your question is "How can I send the change output from a channel funding transaction to a taproot address?"

Comment: @Murch Yes, this is exactly what I mean. I already modified my question in response to your worthy comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of the [`fundchannel`](https://docs.corelightning.org/reference/lightning-fundchannel) command does not appear to make any references to parameters for setting the *addresstype* for the change output of a funding transaction.

However, according to the [announcement of Core Lightning 23.08](https://blog.blockstream.com/core-lightning-v23-08-satoshis-successor/)

> We also added Taproot address support, thanks to Greg Sanders: you can issue Taproot addresses for people to send you on-chain funds, and we will immediately use them for our own change outputs. Taproot addresses (i.e., P2TR) start with `bc1p` instead of `bc1q`, just so you know!

and the [Core Lightning 23.08 Changelog](https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/blob/v23.08/CHANGELOG.md#changed), Core Lightning should generally be creating P2TR change outputs since version 23.08 after pull request [#6035](https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/pull/6035) added *Taproot wallet support*.

If you are running an older version, you should hopefully see the desired behavior after upgrading. If you are running version 23.08 or later and your funding transactions do not have P2TR change outputs, you might want to report a bug to the Core Lightning developers.